# jQuery .toggle() + addClass() doesn't seem to have desired effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a link `<a>` with two different backgrounds, one a "Down Arrow" and one an "Up Arrow" depending on the classname `arrow-up` and `arrow-down`.

So when you click on the **down arrow**, the div named `product-add-wrapper` slides down, and the **down arrow* becomes an **up arrow** and vice versa.

The problem is, the .toggle + callback seems to work fine, it adds the desired class name and removes the desired class name, however, the background-image doesn't change (the down arrow doesn't become an up arrow).

Here is the html.

```html
<span class="arrow-right">
    <a class="updown arrow-down">&nbsp;</a>
</span>
```

Here is the css.

```css
.updown {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

.arrow-up {
    background-image: url('../img/arrow-up.png');
}

.arrow-down {
    background-image: url('../img/arrow-down.png');
}
```

And here is the javascript.

```js
$('.updown').click(function() {
    $('#product-add-wrapper').toggle('slow', function() {
        var classname = $('.updown').attr('class');
        if (classname === 'up arrow-down') {
            $('.updown').removeClass('arrow-down').addClass('arrow-up');
        } else {
            $('.updown').removeClass('arrow-up').addClass('arrow-down');
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how it could be adding the proper class. This doesn't add up: `$('.up')` and `<a class="updown arrow-down">`. AKA change `.up` to `.updown`.

Comment: Where is element with `up` class?

Comment: I've updated the javascript, please note.

Comment: `if (classname === 'up arrow-down') {` is still wrong. If that's what you have in your actual code, then the else case will always be evaluated.

Comment: @crush i'm not sure I understand? What I want is, the toggle to check if 'up arrow-down' is the classname, fire the .addClass + .removeClass. Else, I want it to fire the same thing just switch classes.

Comment: `up arrow-down` will never be the class name because the class name is actually `updown arrow-down` or `updown arrow-up`

Comment: @JOe - the toggle works fine on mine, it "slides Up + Down" the div, however, it is not changing the classname of the <a> in order to change the arrow from up to down.

Comment: @Joe I will try your fiddle... It worked. Please answer so I can attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classname will never be 'up arrow-down' you probably meant 'updown arrow-down'.

```
if (classname === 'up arrow-down') {
```

This would probably be better rewritten like this:

```
$('.updown').click(function() {
    $('#product-add-wrapper').toggle('slow', function() {
        if ($('.updown').hasClass('arrow-down')) {
            $('.updown').removeClass('arrow-down').addClass('arrow-up');
        } else {
            $('.updown').removeClass('arrow-up').addClass('arrow-down');
        }
    });
});
```

Or better yet:
Js:

```
$('.updown').click(function() {
    $('#product-add-wrapper').toggle('slow', function() {
        $('.updown').toggleClass('arrow-up');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.updown {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-image: url('../img/arrow-down.png');
    color:green;
}

.arrow-up {
    background-image: url('../img/arrow-up.png');
    color:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="arrow-right">
    <a class="updown">&nbsp;aa</a>
</span>
<div id="product-add-wrapper">
    aa
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kingmotley/K7274/1/

Comment: Great "better yet" solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is using the `.click()` event handler instead of toggle:

```
$('.updown').click(function (){ 
    if ($(this).hasClass("arrow-down")){ 
        $('#product-add-wrapper').slideUp("slow");
        $(this).removeClass('arrow-down').addClass('arrow-up');
    } else { 
        $('#product-add-wrapper').slideDown("slow");
        $(this).removeClass('arrow-up').addClass('arrow-down');
    };
});
```

HTML as follows:

```
<span class="arrow-right">
    <a class="updown arrow-down">&nbsp;</a>
</span>

<div id="product-add-wrapper">
    ... DIV CONTENT ...
</div>
```

Working demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/9wxfJ/3/

Comment: Hard to answer this with the erroneous code that has been posted by the original author. This wouldn't work either as there is no element that has an element with the class `up`. Your approach is good, though.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, using hasClass:

```
    $('.updown').click(function() {
        $('#product-add-wrapper').toggle('slow', function() {
            if($('.updown').hasClass('arrow-down')) {
                $('.updown').addClass('arrow-up');
                $('.updown').removeClass('arrow-down');
            } else {
                $('.updown').addClass('arrow-down');
                $('.updown').removeClass('arrow-up');
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RP294/

Comment: Although, I would not put this on the callback function. I would have it change onClick.

Answer (score 0):

Work fine for me

http://jsfiddle.net/Hzmxc/

```
$('.updowns').click(function() {
    $('#product-add-wrapper .updown').toggle('slow', function() {
        if ($('.updowns').hasClass('arrow-down')) {
            $('.updowns').removeClass('arrow-down').addClass('arrow-up');
        } else {
            $('.updowns').removeClass('arrow-up').addClass('arrow-down');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd go about this using one class instead of two since you know the element you're working with has a default state. So instead of having an .arrow-down class, just give that background to the .updown class and have the .arrow-up class use !important to overrule it when toggled:

HTML

```
<span class="arrow-right">
    <a class="updown">&nbsp;</a>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.updown {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-image: url('../img/arrow-down.png');

}

.arrow-up {
    background-image: url('../img/arrow-up.png') !important;
}
```

This will also shorten your javascript code quite a bit:

```
$('body').on('click', '.updown', function(e){
    var arrow = $(this);
    $('#product-add-wrapper').toggle('slow', function() {
      arrow.toggleClass('arrow-up');
    });
});
```